# single file generator in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i took the XmlClassGenerator sample of the visual studio 2010 sdk.
in the visual studio 2010 experimental instance it's working and generating c# file from xml file.
but in the normal visual studio 2010 this cutom tool does not work.i get a warning "Cannot find custom tool 'XmlClassGenerator' on this system".

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the experimental instance, your Extension is automatically registered with Visual Studio. In order to use it in the standard installation, you have to register it yourself. See this [topic on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166527%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: i try the link you gave and it's still don't work. maybe i need a pkgdef file for my custom tool code generator?

Comment: i solved the problem, need to add registry entries in the HKLM Wow6432Node because i am running win7 64bit. and add my custom tool assembly to the GAC.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to Wow6432Node. One more thing I had to do was run devenv.exe /setup (from a VS 2012 command prompt), to make the changes show up in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Generators